# Shadow gradient inside div

Tags: css

I'm trying to emulate the way this site does their shadow gradient inside divs ( http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/roi-calculator/#headline )

Check this picture

[image]

Not sure how to get the border shadow portion that the arrows point to

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an image they are using to do it. This is their [source sprite sheet](http://static.zeroturnaround.org/theme5/images/gfx-s1d3748b122.png)

That specific border image in near the bottom.

I agree with you though, it looks good and I wish it was possible in pure code but I'm sure if that's possible yet, or else I'd be able to help you more.

By the way, I suggest you get the [Firebug add on for Firefox](https://getfirebug.com/). All I had to do was right click in that area and inspect with firebug and it told me right away what exactly that border was created from.

Comment: thanks. yea i thought it is most likely an image; it seemed too 'specific' to render using css. firebug it is ! cheers